# When will this open to the public?

Tags: discussion, beta-phase, private-beta

When will the Open Source Stack Exchange open to the public? Will this be a quick process or will it be a while before this happens?

How will it work?

Answer (score 7):

We're currently in private beta, a phase where we build up a bit of a backlog of questions and answers, to scope the site out for when it enters the next phase...

...which is unsurprisingly called public beta. The private beta is a fairly short phase, usually lasting no more than 2 weeks, so we should go public soon. The switch is very simple for us: we do nothing. The Stack Exchange team flip a switch and *boom* the site's public.

Comment: "[..] we should go public soon." That is, if the Stack Exchange team is pleased with how the private beta went.